# how can i put the Radio Button horizontal?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

the radio button is vertical, and i need it in horizontal, how can i do this?

this is my code:

HTML:

```
 <section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="login-form">
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <form method="get">
<input type="radio" name="Client" value="Clientes" onclick="this.form.action = 'ContactoTropical.html'" > Clientes <br> <br>
```

Empleados

CSS:

```
section{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 340px;
    text-align: center;}

.login-form{
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 60px 30px;}

.login-form input{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    outline: none;}
```

please help

Comment: Do you mean you have several radio buttons and you need to render them horizontally?

Comment: yes, i want it in horizontal but in my html when i put text and the radiobutton is vertical

Comment: What do u mean it’s vertical? Can u turn ur code into a snippet so we could see what’a going on?

Answer (score 0):

According your explanation you want to get your radio button and the label for it in the same line. You have to remove the `width: 100%` style for the input and use `display: inline-block` to render them in line.

```css
section{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 340px;
    text-align: center;}

.login-form{
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 60px 30px;}

.login-form input{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    outline: none;}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="login-form">
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <form method="get">
<input type="radio" name="Client" value="Clientes" onclick="this.form.action = 'ContactoTropical.html'" >
<span>Clientes</span>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks, that is what i want, thanks so mucho. love you

Comment: @MiguelAC, Accept the answer, please, if you're satisfied it.